# How to display the unique elements between two object lists?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have two lists filled with object elements. Using these two lists, I want to create another list which contains only the uncommon elements between them.

I tried using an iterator:

```
for(Row currentRowObject: currentRow) {
    for (Iterator<Row> newError = newErrorRow.iterator(); newError.hasNext(); ) {
        Row rowObject = newError.next();
        if (rowObject.getAll().equals(currentRowObject.getAll())) {
            newError.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

After I run this, the `newError` list is completely removed. I checked that the two lists are different, they differ in size and there are objects that differ between these two lists.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to explain this in logic format(not Java):

```
UncommonRows = (currentRow union newErrorRow ) - (currentRow intersection newErrorRow)
```

here is a quick and dirty way of doing it in Java. hope the comments explains what I've done.

```
Set<Row> uncommonRows=new HashSet<Row>(currentRow);
uncommonRows.addAll(newErrorRow); //at this point uncommonRows contains all the Rows
Set<Row> retained=new HashSet<Row>(currentRow);
retained.retainAll(newErrorRow); //retained contains all rows that are in both sets.
uncommonRows.removeAll(retained) ; // at this point uncommonRows contains the uncommon Rows
```

Comment: @JohnSmith could you upload how you defined your class Row. you must have equal(Object o) and hashCode() method overridden (make them unique) this link should help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: @JohnSmith btw make sure, u print out uncommonRows :)

Comment: @vefthym yeah, I think not having equals method was the reason why the original method didn't work to begin with

Comment: I solved the problem, the reason was I inversed the lists by mistake that's why it didn't worked, I was confused why it doesn't work because I had the equals and hashcode methods :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sets [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) property & the use [removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) !

```
Set < Row > rows1 = new HashSet(currentRow);
Set < Row > rows2 = new HashSet(newErrorRow);
rows1.retainAll(rows2); // rows1 now contains only elements in both set !
rows2.removeAll(rows1); // rows2 now contains only the unique elements !
```

Comment: +1/ You can initialize `row1` as `Set<Row> row1 = new HashSet<>(currentRow);` and do the same for `row2` with `newErrorRow`. And also fix the typo  in retai**l**All to retai**n**All.

Comment: I just saw that the OP asks for the uncommon elements!

Comment: I think that it's still wrong, as you are missing the unique elements of currentRow. I think nafas' solution is where you are getting to sooner or later, but my first thoughts were exactly the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Using java8 you can do something like:

```
    final List<Row> allErrors = new ArrayList<>();
    allErrors.addAll(currentRow);
    allErrors.addAll(newErrorRow);
```

and then:

```
final List<Row> result = allErrors.stream().filter(p -> Collections.frequency(allErrors, p) == 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```